# Url Error in Multiple Application Django site

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-urls

My site has 3 applications [alpha, store, management].

`alpha` for landing page, login, about, contact and similar pages

`store` e-com like page,
`management` for system admin and management

github: @Torzen/Jerry

I have urls.py in  all my  applications
And everything runs well first but when try request to in app urls it didn't worked..

Main urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('services',include('store.urls')),
    path('management',include('management.urls')),
    path('',include('alpha.urls'))
]
```

First application url for store

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.main,name = "main"),
    path('track',views.track,name="tracker")
]
```

Second application url for management

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.main ,name=''),
    path('staffs',views.staffs ,name='staffs'),
    path('customers',views.customers,name='customers'),
    path('services',views.services ,name='services'),
    path('delete',views.delete ,name='delete'),
    path('add',views.add ,name='add'),
    path('crm',views.crm ,name='crm'),
    path('ratings',views.ratings ,name='ratings'),
    path('complainBox',views.complainBox,name = 'complainBox'),
    path('registrationApproval',views.registrationApproval ,name='registrationApproval'),
    path('feedbacks',views.feedbacks,name = "feedbacks"),
    path('contact',views.contact,name = "Contact"),
    path('datasets',views.datasets,name = "Dataset page"),
    path('tools',views.tools,name ="Tools page" ),
    path('services',views.services,name ="services page" ),
    path('reports',views.reports,name ="reports page" ),
    path('login',views.login,name="Login page") ,
    path('forgetPassword',views.forgetPassword,name = "Forget password")
]
```

3rd application url for alpha

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.main,name='Main page'),
    path('about',views.about , name="About page"),
    path('contact',views.contact,name='contact page'),
    path('register',views.register,name='Staff registration'),
    path('patners',views.patners ,name="patner page"),
    path('alumuni',views.alumuni,name="Alumini page"),
    path('help',views.help , name = "help page"),
    path('complain',views.complain,name="Complain page"),
    path('feedback',views.feedback,name = "feedback page"),
    path('plans',views.plans,name = "plans and visions"),
    path('team',views.team,name = "team page")
]
```

[management page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZNc.png)

When i click to tools or other link it is showing me like this
[Img of page when i try tool menu link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZJ1.png)

**What should I doo ?**
Anyone help plzz!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your URLs are working as expected is because using `include()`  with appends those included urls to the path you have specified. So in your example, all of your management urls are appended to `yoursite.com/management/` - your `tools` url will be at `yoursite.com/management/tools`.

```py
path('management',include('management.urls')),
```

If you don't want this to happen then set the first path argument to an empty string.